# Junit как узнать, synchronized ли метод?

Tags: java, junit

Проблема - в заголовке. Вообще, у меня лабораторная работа, где два из заданий - по тестам:

1. Подпроцессы должны уведомлять друг друга о готовности очередной проции данных с помощью `wait()` и `notify()`. Синхронизировать подпроцессы таким образом, чтобы тесты, которые проверяют, была ли выполнена такая синхронизация, считались не пройденными при отсутствии вызова `wait()`.
2. Синхронизировать доступ к общим данным таким образом, чтобы тесты, которые проверяют, была ли выполнена такая синхронизация, считались не пройденными при отсутствии ключевого слова `synchronized`.

Кроме этого, я не знаю, как выполнить второй пункт. `wait()` и `notify()` - сделал, но как проверить, что есть вызов?

P.S. Обычно здесь прикрепляют код, но тут он вроде не нужен.

Comment: ответ уже не нужен, как пометить тему как "ответ найден"?

Comment: а, нашел, все ок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проверить соответствующий модификатор у метода, используя рефлексию:

```
Method method = getClass().getDeclaredMethod(...);
Modifier.isSynchronized(method.getModifiers())
```

Метод `isSynchronized()` возвращает `true`, если метод синхронизирован, и `false` в противном случае. Тут всё очевидно.

Comment: Да, я тоже подумал про рефлексию. Но на нашем уровне "только что подошли к потокам" это как-то слишком сложно. Все оказалось гораздо проще, нужно было показать, что без synchronized метод не будет работать.